# How does apache PHP memory usage really work?

Tags: php, memory, process, apache2

To give some context:

I had a discussion with a colleague recently about the use of Autoloaders in PHP. I was arguing in favour of them, him against.

My point of view is that Autoloaders can help you minimise manual source dependency which in turn can help you reduce the amount of memory consumed when including lots of large files that you may not need.

His response was that including files that you do not need is not a big problem because after a file has been included once it is kept in memory by the Apache child process and this portion of memory will be available for subsequent requests. He argues that you should not be concerned about the amount of included files because soon enough they will all be loaded into memory and used on-demand from memory. Therefore memory is less of an issue and the overhead of trying to find the file you need on the filesystem is much more of a concern.

He's a smart guy and tends to know what he's talking about. However, I always thought that the memory used by Apache and PHP was specific to that particular request being handled. 
Each request is assigned an amount of memory equal to memory_limit PHP option and any source compilation and processing is only valid for the life of the request.

Even with op-code caches such as APC, I thought that the individual request still needs to load up each file in it's own portion of memory and that APC is just a shortcut to having it pre-compiled for the responding process.

I've been searching for some documentation on this but haven't managed to find anything so far. I would really appreciate it if someone can point me to any useful documentation on this topic.

**UPDATE:**

Just to clarify, the autoloader discussion part was more of a context :).

It may not have been clear but my main question is about whether Apache will pool together its resources to respond to multiple requests (especially memory used by included files), or whether each request will need to retrieve the code required to satisfy the execution path in isolation from other requests handled from the same process.

e.g.:
Files 1, 2, 3 and 4 are an equal size of 100KB each.
Request A includes file 1, 2 and 3. 
Request B includes file 1, 2, 3 and 4.

In his mind he's thinking that Request A will consume 300KB for the entirety of it's execution and Request B will only consume a further 100KB because files 1,2 and 3 are already in memory.

In my mind it's 300KB and 400KB because they are both being processed independently (if by the same process).

This brings him back to his argument that "just include the lot 'cos you'll use it anyway" as opposed to my "only include what you need to keep the request size down".

This is fairly fundamental to how I approach building a PHP website, so I would be keen to know if I'm off the mark here.

I've also always been of the belief that for large-scale website memory is the most precious resource and more of a concern than file-system checks for an autoloader that are probably cached by the kernel anyway.

You're right though, it's time to benchmark!

Answer (score 4):

Here's how you win arguments: run realistic benchmark, and be on the right side of the numbers.

I've had this same discussion, so I tried an experiment. Using APC, I tried a Kohana app with a single monolithic include (containing all of Kohana) as well as with the standard autoloader. The final result was that the single include was faster at a statistically irrelevant rate (less than 1%) but used slightly more memory (according to PHP's memory functions). Running the test without APC (or XCache, etc) is pointless, so I didn't bother.

So my conclusion was to continue use autoloading because it's much simpler to use. Try the same thing with your app and show your friend the results.

Now you don't need to guess.

Disclaimer: I wasn't using Apache. I cannot emphasize enough to run your own benchmarks on your own hardware on your own app. Don't trust that my experience will be yours.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, I've made an edit to the original post just in case that helps, but I'll definitely run some tests!

Comment: I'm not sure how mod_php handles serving the same page, but if you use an opcode cache, then the PHP files themselves will definitely be in shared memory. The way I understand vanilla PHP, is that on each request the file is opened, parsed, and executed ... so I'm not sure where the memory sharing would be occurring. I think it still comes down to benchmarking ... use something like `ab` to run tests. I'm sure you'll see that whether or not you use Autoloading comes down to personal preference ... I don't think performance will be significantly different.

Answer (score 2):

You are the wiser ninja, grasshopper.

Autoloaders don't load the class file until the class is requested.  This means that they will use at most the same amount memory as manual includes, but usually much less.

Classes get read fresh from file each request even if an apache thread can handle multiple requests, so your friends 'eventuall all are read' doesn't hold water.

You can prove this by putting an echo 'foo'; above the class definition in the class file.  You'll see on each new request the line will be executed regardless of if you autoload or manually include the whole world of class files at start.

I couldn't find any good concise documentation on this--i may write some with some memory usage examples--as i also have had to explain this to others and show evidence to get it to sink in.  I think the folks at zend didn't think anyone would not see the benifits of autoloading.

Yes, apc and such (like all caching solutions) can overcome the resouce negatives and even eek out small gains in performance, but you eat up lots of unneeded memory if you do this on a non-trivial number of libraries and serving a large number of clients. Try something Like loading a healthy chunk of the pear libraries in a massive include file while handling 500 connections hitting your page at the same time.

Even using things like Apc you benefit from using autoloaders with any non-namespaced classes (most of the existing php code currently) as it can help avoid global namespace pollution when dealing with large  umbers of class libraries.

Answer (score 0):

This is my opionion.

I think autoloaders are a very bad idea for the following reasons

1. I like to know what and where my scripts are grabbing the data/code from. Makes debugging easier.
2. This also has configuration problems in so far as if one of your developers changes the file (upgrade etc) or configuration and things stop working it is harder to find out where it is broken.
3. I also think that it is lazy programming.

As to memory/preformance issues it is just as cheap to buy some more memory for the computer if it is struggling with that.

Comment: could you elaborate a bit on why you think that this is lazy programming? I'm curious because it seems reasonable enough to have an autoloader function.

Comment: @Dave - I think that it is lazy not to be explicit as to what constitues your script and rely on the interpreter to find the appropriate code. It also helps with the documentation and future maintenance. Why is it so much effort to type in `require`?

Comment: @Ed it can be argued that, all things being equal, a lazy programmer is better than one who's working hard all the time

Comment: Ed your responses are from a stylistic approach rather than efficiency. I would say that personally I disagree with your reasoning:

1. Most autoloader users operate via a convention that makes it very, very obvious where your code is coming from. Also most modern IDEs will easily jump to the correct file for reading/debugging your code.
2. Same, I don't see this.
3. If you design your codebase in a sensible way so that you can expect each class/file to be available to each script that needs it, I personally would not consider this lazy.

Comment: Whether or not it's good is just an opinion (as you state). Whether or not it performs better is a fact that can be tested. Sirhara's question is about the latter. Anyway, to weigh in on the subjective angle, in my experience the biggest negative of avoiding autoloading is that people then tend to avoid writing well designed, object oriented code because they grow weary of specifying dozens of includes. But I have nothing against manual includes, especially if I'm getting paid by the line. ;)

Comment: @mathew - I just think that it is sometimes better to make code maintainable, readable and easy to understand/document. I think that it is sometimes a lot cheaper to just increase the computers performance through hardware.